# TCustomControl does not trigger the Paint method

Tags: delphi-xe

I have the following code:

```
tExCustomControl = class (tCustomControl)
private
  procedure Paint; override;
end; 

tMyControl : class (tExCustomControl)
private
  procedure Paint; override;
public
  constructor Create (AOwner: TComponent);
...
end;
...
implementation
{ tExCustomControl }
procedure tExCustomControl.Paint;
begin
  inherited;
  ...
end;

{ tMyControl }
procedure tMyControl.Paint (Sender: TObject);
begin
  inherited;
  ...
end;
```

It was working fine, but for some reason, now is not triggering no one of the `Paint` methods. Can anyone tell me what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Should I add any enlightment? Isn't the question clear enough? I mean, if  for instance, the bounds of `TMyControl` are changed, the event should trigger the `Paint`method of the `TExCustomControl`, correct?

Comment: My question was somehow so stupid that noone thinks is worth to answer it? Please, any answer. Thanks.

Comment: You haven't included any code that shows how the component is being used that will allow us to try to reproduce the problem. Can you edit again to include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to try and troubleshoot this?

Comment: @Ken. After digging into my code, I realized that the `Paint` method is not triggered because the `ClientRect` of the control that is to be painted is actually out of the `Parent's` bounds. Hence, the `Paint` method wasn't ment to be triggered. So the real problem resides on the code that calculates the `ClientRect` coordinates. I'm modifying the code sample to reflect the actual conditions. I hope this can help. For now, can you please tell me if `ClientToScreen` is based on the `Owner's` or the `Parent's` as a reference to calculate the `Screen` coordinates?

Comment: The parent is where it's displayed, so it would be the `Parent` coordinates. The owner is what is responsible for freeing the control when the owner is being destroyed, but the Parent is the visual container where the control is shown.

Comment: Yes. I figured so. But I was in doubt because of the odd results I got when getting the screen coordinates for the edit control that I use as reference to place a box with a message (something like a callout with a pointer). That whas also a mistake because I should use the Left and Top properties of the form, instead of translate them to screen coordinates.

Comment: I placed an edit control inside a panel that at the same time was inside a second panel and all of them at 0,0 Left,Top. Strangely I got a 2,2 displacement for the edit control and I can't figure out why is it so :(. Any way, the issue now is about the way I calculate the coordinates to position the textbox. The thing is that when all the controls are at 0,0, the textbox is correctly placed, but if I move any of the controls to any other coordinates than 0,0 the textbox's Left,Top coordinates are displaced by some pixels. So now I'm checking why this is happening.

Comment: You've *still not posted any code* that can be used to figure out what the issue is, and the question you're asking in comments no longer has anything to do with the question you've posted. I'm voting to close this question as "unclear what you're asking" until you [edit] the question to make it clear what problem you're having, **post the relevant code** (including actual, runnable code that demonstrates the problem), and ask a specific question that can be answered.

Comment: @Ken. As a matter of fact, I was wondering if I could close this question. Is it possible?